# Facing a big issue in importing package to flutter (Andriod Studio). I have tried all the methods from other solutions

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart-pub

I am trying to import the URL launcher package but it seems that the flutter is not able to recognize the package.

I have mentioned about the package in pubspec.yaml file.
I have also used the command `flutter packages get`. I can see the package imported in external libraries but not able to import it. There seems to be a problem with 
 `import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';`

For your reference, I have pasted my error message, my code and pubspec.yaml file too

I received the following error

```
Error: Could not resolve the package 'url_launcher' in 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart'.
lib/main.dart:2:8: Error: Not found: 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart'
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
       ^
lib/main.dart:8:5: Error: The method 'launch' isn't defined for the class 'XylophoneApp'.
 - 'XylophoneApp' is from 'package:xylophone/main.dart' ('lib/main.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'launch'.
    launch('https://flutter.dev');
    ^^^^^^
```

The following is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() => runApp(XylophoneApp());

class XylophoneApp extends StatelessWidget {
  launchURL() {
    launch('https://flutter.dev');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Xylophone'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: launchURL,
            child: Text('Show Flutter homepage'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my pubspec.yaml file

```
name: xylophone
description: A new Flutter application.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  url_launcher: ^5.4.0


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/
```

Answer (score 1):

Always restart the program after importing any package.
Use the run button instead of the hot reload or hot restart button